# Term for someone who lost something

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, agent-nouns

Is there any specific term for someone who has lost something? The person who finds something can be called a finder but what about the person who has lost something? What should the appropriate term be?

Comment: Finders keepers, losers weepers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term that describes a person who misplaces an inanimate object is *[mislayer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mislayer)* (a derivative of *mislay*).

> He constantly loses his wallet; I don't know a more frequent *mislayer*.

Additionally, a term that denotes a person who lost someone dear (or something sentimental) is *[bereaved](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bereaved)* (or *bereft*), when used as an [adjectival noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectival_noun_%28noun%29).

> I offer my condolences to *the bereft*.

Comment: People who lose their billfolds are now Don Juans? :)

Comment: @tchrist There's a reason this "Don Juan" has lost his wallet; it was probably stolen by an unscrupulous woman that he seduced (or payed for).

Comment: @AldeeMativo My pleasure. When in doubt, use a thesaurus. Although initially I could find no synonyms for "loser", I looked at synonyms for the verb "lose". In one of the dictionary entries for "mislay" (a synonym of "lose"), I found "mislayer" among the derived terms. There are many descriptive words in English, but it sometimes takes some excavation to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I think aside from the rather abrasive "loser", such a term doesn't exist. For specific things however, e.g. the loss of a wife/husband, we have the term "widow/widower".

Comment: Yes. I agree.. it seems there is no specific term for such :)